# How to use CMake cached variables inside subprocess called by custom target?

Tags: cmake, add-custom-target, cmake-cache

My project contains a custom target which generates some output via `.cmake` script. It looks like this:

```
add_custom_target(TargetName
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/script.cmake
    BYPRODUCTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated/output
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
    VERBATIM
)
```

But now I want to set come cache variables inside the script. I tried doing like that:

```
message("MY_CACHE_VARIABLE = ${MY_CACHE_VARIABLE}")
set(MY_CACHE_VARIABLE "VALUE" CACHE INTERNAL "")
```

And I faced with the problem that cache variables are not saved. It always prints me empty output:

```
MY_CACHE_VARIABLE =
```

I already tried setting working directory as `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`, or passing `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` of the last argument of cmake command, or passing `-B ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` or `-C ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeCache.txt` as arguments and etc. None of these worked.
So is there any way to reuse existing cache inside CMake subprocess or I just should write my own cache inside the script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to distinguish between running CMake to generate build files (for Make, Ninja, etc.) and running CMake in script mode:

> Script mode simply runs the commands in the given CMake Language source file and does not generate a build system. It does not allow CMake commands that define build targets or actions.
> -- [cmake-language(7)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#scripts)

> No configure or generate step is performed and the cache is not modified.
> -- [cmake(1)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-script)

So in script mode (`-P`), CMake is not aware of the cache or any variable/target/etc. defined in your regular `CMakeLists.txt` files. It is more similar to executing a bash/shell script than to processing a "usual" `CMakeLists.txt`.

But don't worry, there is still a solution to your problem. You can simply pass your arguments as `-D` options to your script:

```cpp
add_custom_target(TargetName
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
    -DMY_VAR="..."
    -DANOTHER_VAR="..."
    -P ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/script.cmake
  ...
)
```

Note however:

> If variables are defined using `-D`, this must be done before the `-P` argument.
> -- [cmake(1)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-script)